# Как кликнув по тексту добавить этот текст в поле поиска?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.word span {
border-bottom:1px dotted #006fff; 
font-size:14px;
color:#006fff;
margin:0px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" class="megasearch" size="40" placeholder="Текст для поиска..." >
  <button>Искать</button>
</div>
<p class="word">
 Например:  <span>Холодильник Bosch</span>  <span>Печь Indesit</span>
</p>
```

Требуется после клика по любому из span в блоке с классом .word найти на странице поле с классом .megasearch и вставить текст из span в это поле.

Подскажите, как это оформит в виде скрипта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.word span {
border-bottom:1px dotted #006fff; 
font-size:14px;
color:#006fff;
margin:0px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" class="megasearch" size="40" placeholder="Текст для поиска..." >
  <button>Искать</button>
</div>
<p class="word">
 Например:  <span>Холодильник Bosch</span>  <span>Печь Indesit</span>
</p>
```

```js
$('.word span').on('click', function() {
  $('#search').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.word span {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #006fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #006fff;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" class="megasearch" size="40" placeholder="Текст для поиска..." id="search">
  <button>Искать</button>
</div>
<p class="word">
  Например: <span>Холодильник Bosch</span> <span>Печь Indesit</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как всегда от вас очень простое и рабочее решение!!

Comment: Подскажите, а возможно с помощью скрипта еще и инициировать поиск,   я имею ввиду после клика по словосочетанию примеру, оно не только подставлялось в поле поиска, но и автоматически нажималась кнопка "Искать"  и начинался поиск (по примеру как это в настоящий момент на главной странице у Яндекс )

Comment: Спасибо Hans Helmut если добавить в скрипт строку $( ".form button" ).click(); то начинает еще и автоматически искать по словосочетанию примеру